# Cannot rebase to second git commit message in history?

Tags: git, github

I have stumbled upon a problem in the following repo, I cannot rebase to the commit (one before the most recent one) in order to change the commit message (as there is a typo and I would like to amend this). It might seem petty, however I would love to learn more about git by solving this problem.

When I type `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, that particular message is not shown (added: x.com requiremet), however I can see it in the git commit history here.

https://github.com/calwoodford/gaza_citizenjournalism/commits/main

In fact, when I type `git rebase -i HEAD~3`, I am shown 7 commits, some duplicates etc, and not the one I actually want to change (added: x.com requiremet)

```
pick d4f9bb5 added: mariam barghouti
pick 191d6fb added: abdalrahim alfarra
pick be5f610 added: dr. yara hawari
pick c6dfeb8 added: aya isleem
pick ea9af60 added: sarah hassan
pick d6c3bb2 added: mariam barghouti
pick 541ca0a added: abdalrahim alfarra
```

If anyone knows what might be wrong, I would be incredibly grateful if you'd please let me know how I might be able to solve this.

Tried:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Expecting:

```
added: abdalrahim alfarra  u/calwoodford
Merge branch 'main' of https://github.com/calwoodford/gaza_citizenjou…   @calwoodford
added: x.com requiremet
```

Comment: If you see more commits that means that one of the commits you are trying to rebase is a merge commit. This will flatten the history and you see the commits of both sides of the merge

Answer (score 0):

First, don't rebase your `main` branch once it has been pushed.  To quote the [git documentation on rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) (which puts it mildly):

> One of the cardinal rules of Git is that, since so much work is local within your clone, you have a great deal of freedom to rewrite your history *locally*. However, once you push your work, it is a different story entirely, and you should consider pushed work as final unless you have good reason to change it. In short, you should avoid pushing your work until you’re happy with it and ready to share it with the rest of the world.

Case in point, I was about to help you, but you blew away your commits, and now I can no longer see them, and can only guess at what was wrong.  Rebase is for local changes.  Once you push a branch, you shouldn't rebase it.  This is particularly true for your main branch.

You have a couple of problems.  First, the way you are specifying your upstream with `HEAD~3`.  This points at the first parent of the first parent of the first parent of `HEAD`.  A couple of things to keep in mind:

- Merge commits have more than one parent, and you had a merge commit in your history.
- Git doesn't always (or even usually) present commits in parent->child order.  It is date based by default, and so it's very common for the commit order to be presented in a way that is wildly different from the parent->child order.

So, perhaps you can see now that the `HEAD~N` syntax is not as simple as it seems.  You might expect, when looking at your commit list, that `HEAD~3` means the third commit, but that is not always the case (even though it frequently is).

It would be better to be more precise in specifying your upstream.  You want to rebase starting from the parent of the commit you're trying to reword.  So, copy the hash from the commit you want to reword, then get its parent commit by adding a caret to the end.  Eg, `ab123cde^`

```bash
$ git rebase ab123cde^ -i
```

Your second problem is that you are trying to rebase a branch containing merge commits.  If the branch you are rebasing includes a merge commit, you're almost always going to lose that merge commit, and end up with just the individual commits in  a new order, that you specify.  Since you weren't anticipating this, it's an extra complication, and understandably confusing.  Instead of just rewording a commit and moving on, you'd have to completely undo and redo the merge, resolving all the conflicts again, this time one commit at a time instead of all at once.  That's probably a lot more complicated than you were hoping for, when all you wanted to do was fix a typo in a commit message, but that's the reality of git.

But, seriously.  Don't rebase your `main` branch once it has been pushed.